# How can I calculate percentages as a new row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012 and I am trying to calculate the percentage of a target value using PARTITION but I keep getting aggregate errors. The percentage needs to be a new row in the dataset, appended to the end of each group

[image: Sample]

Comment: Show us your code plus the error message. Some sample data would be nice in the form of a sql statement.

Comment: Which errors are you getting? What have you already tried? Can you place your code as a snippet here?

Comment: Your desired results are strange.  You seem to want integers on some rows and decimals on other rows.  SQL columns should have only a single type.  You probably want to do this manipulation in the reporting layer.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have you tried something ? Did you have already a query ?

Comment: Are your actual numbers entered manually, or are they the result of another query/view? I'm not sure what your actual requirements are, but this sort of calculation would be a lot easier if your target and actual metrics were on the same row, rather than having separate rows for each metric.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want, although I'm skeptical about how useful it is:

```
select group, item, jan, feb
from ((select group, item, jan * 1.0 as jan, feb * 1.0 as feb
       from t
      ) union all
      (select group, 'Percent',
              sum(case when item = 'Target' then jan end) * 1.0 / sum(case when item = 'Target' then jan end),
              sum(case when item = 'Target' then feb end) * 1.0 / sum(case when item = 'Target' then feb end)
       from t
       group by group
      )
     ) g
order by group, charindex(item, 'Target,Actual,Percent');
```

`group` is a reserved word so it is a really bad name for a column.  I haven't bothered to escape the name, because I think that is just a distraction from the query logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
select field1,
perc=field1/sum(field1) over( order by field1 rows between unbounded 
preceding and unbounded following) 
from Table1
```